# How to dynamically update menuItem in MEL script

Tags: loops, maya, mel

I am trying to update a `menuItem` based on the option chosen in another option box. What I actually tying to do is to get a list of folders in one option box (example: project folder names) and when I choose a specific folder (project) in the option box the folders inside that folder are listed in another option box (example: department folder names like animation, modeling, etc.)

```
global proc GetProject_Root() {

    string $projectname ;
    string $dataArray[] ;
    string $tempArray[] ;
    string $project ;
    $i ;
    string $disp ;
    string $m1 ;
    string $m2 ;

    $serverSaveDir = ( `internalVar -userPrefDir` + "ProjectRoot.txt" ) ;
    $serverId = `fopen $serverSaveDir "r"` ;
    int $num = 0 ;

    string $serverLine = `fgetword $serverId` ;

    while ( size( $serverLine ) > 0 ) {

        $dataArray[ size( $dataArray ) ] = $serverLine ;  
        print ( $serverLine ) ;

        if ( $num % 2 == 0 ) {

            $tempArray[size($tempArray)] = $serverLine ;
        }

        // get the next line
        $serverLine = `fgetword  $serverId` ;
        $num++ ;
    }

    fclose $serverId ;

    string $window = `window` ;
    columnLayout ;     
    optionMenu -label "project" -cc "print #1**strong text**" proj ; 

        for ( $projectname in $tempArray ) {

            // print ( $projectname + "\n" ) ;

            $m1 = `menuItem -label $projectname` ;              
        }

    optionMenu -label "Episode" -cc "print #1" epi ;

        for ($projectname in $tempArray) {

            // print ( $projectname + "\n" ) ;

            $m2 = `menuItem -label $projectname` ;
        }                     

    showWindow $window ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to recreate that control when the first one changes.  So when they choose a project folder, delete and recreate the other optionMenu control.  Doesn't look like there is a away to edit items in place